# Ubuntu 20.04 set mysql phpmyadmin root password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords, root, ubuntu-20.04

I installed a LAMP on Ubuntu 20.04.

(German)
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/MySQL/Werkzeuge/

It is always a problem to get the root password to login to the localhost/phpmyadmin. In Ubuntu 18.04 there was a good tutorial (several):

```
SERVER BEENDEN:
  sudo service mysql stop
  sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
  sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
  sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
PRÜFEN MIT:
  jobs
STARTEN von MYSQL:
  mysql -u root
    mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    mysql> USE mysql; 
    mysql> UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") WHERE user='root';
    mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin="mysql_native_password" WHERE User='root';
    mysql> quit
  sudo pkill mysqld
  sudo service mysql start
```

In the actual ubuntu version it seems that the PASSWORD command is not known. I get the following error.

mysql> `UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE user='root';`

**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE user='root'' at line 1**

My mysql version:

mysql  Ver 8.0.19-0ubuntu5 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## There are a few parts to this puzzle

**To change a password**

Login at root from the CLI:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Then

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<New-Password-Here>';
```

## To Really Get Things Working

[From phpmyadmin.net](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/5.0.2/)

> Due to changes in the MySQL authentication method, PHP versions prior to 7.4 are unable to authenticate to a MySQL 8.0 blah *blah blah blah*
>    https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76243.
>
> There is a workaround, that is to set your user account to use the current-style password hash method, mysql_native_password. **This unfortunate lack of coordination has caused the incompatibility to affect all PHP applications, not just phpMyAdmin.**

So

```
UPDATE user SET plugin="mysql_native_password" WHERE user='root';
```

## To Really Really Get Things Working... Really

MySQL Have changed their Security Model and **root login now requires a sudo**. This is ok for the CLI, but it means that **PhpMyAdmin and ALL other clients will not be able to use root credentials**

The best solution is to create a new user for PhpMyAdmin (or use the existing one if it was created during install) and grant it the required privileges.

```
CREATE USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<New-Password-Here>';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Use this user anywhere you want *"root"* access.

---

Also make sure you're using the latest verion of PHP.  Here is my full install script

**PHP**

```
sudo apt install -y php7.4
sudo apt install php7.4-curl php7.4-gd php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring php7.4-xml
```

**APACHE**

```
sudo apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.4
```

**MYSQL**

```
sudo apt install mysql-server php7.4-mysql
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

**PHPMYADMIN**

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```